# Logout automatically from google app engine after certain time interval

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session-cookies

I have an GAE app. in python, using `Federated Login` for authentication purpose with one of its handlers as

```
login:required
```

What I am trying to do is to auto logout from the app. or clearing all the user's session after certain time interval. I have googled around but could not get anything helpful. I am not able to get the direction to go ahead.

As I am using Federated Login, I feel I need to clear user's Google session ? Please correct if I am wrong.

Can anybody give me proper direction in which I should go ahead, to autologout after certain time interval ?

Answer (score 1):

In Application Setting you can manage the cookies expiration times (top-right). You can choose  one day, one week and two weeks. After this time interval your app does a log out to all your app's users.
If this is not enough and, for example, you need a more precise control, you should delete GAE related cookies during the response.

Comment: Thanks. I need more precise control. I need custom timeouts userwise. What are GAE related cookies? Where can I find that and clear it ?

Comment: 1- cookies generate from google app engine. 2- In browser's developers tools. Delete cookies named SACSID or ACSID when you need. Your python web frameworks has dedicated methods to manage cookies.